# Parametrization of the circle

Tags: geometry

Here's the question:
A particle moves in a circle (center $0$ and radius $R$) with constant angular velocity $w$ counterclockwise. The circle lies in the $xy$ plane and the particle is on the $x$ axis at time $t = 0$. Show that the
particle's position is given by
$r(t) = \hat{x}R \cos(wt) + \hat{y}R \sin(wt)$.

Alright, so given anypoint $p$ on the circle, I can easily show that the the $x$ coordinate is given by $R\cos(wt)$ and the $y$ coordinate is given by $R\sin(wt)$.

I know that $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions get values between $-1$ and $1,$ so $p$ cannot be outside of the circle...but anyway I already assumed that $p$ was a point of the circle so I don't know why I bother with this.
I just can't convince myself that for all $t$ the point $p=(R\cos(wt),R\sin(wt))$ will be only on the circle.
Any minds? Thanks!

Comment: Since it is conventional to use the letter $\omega$ in this context, I wonder if you meant $\omega$ rather than $w. \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn’t it clear that the coordinates $(x,y)$ of $p(t)$ satisfy the equation $x^2+y^2=R^2$?

Comment: Oh, what a shame...Thanks for your help! I didn't see that  obvious relation.. you're a nice human!

Comment: Note, however, that it is patently FALSE that if a point travels on this circle, then its coordinates at time $t$ are $(R\cos \omega t,R\sin \omega t)$. They need only be $(R\cos f(t),R\sin f(t))$ for some function $f$. It is the hypothesis of constant angular velocity that establishes the particular function $f(t)= \omega t$.